# Why can't show the response in console.log's window when to call a js api?

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

It is a simple api to call stock's price.

```
http://hq.sinajs.cn/list=sh
```

Add a stock's ticker at the end of `sh`.Type `http://hq.sinajs.cn/list=sh600020` in  browser,a long string containing stock' price as response to `http://hq.sinajs.cn/list=sh600020`.

```
var hq_str_sh600020="中原高速,3.530,3.530,3.560,3.590,3.520,3.560,3.570,4517058,16087830.000,169746,3.560,114392,3.550,108100,3.540,153300,3.530,100000,3.520,129998,3.570,241810,3.580,346700,3.590,223900,3.600,148900,3.610,2018-09-19,15:00:00,00";
```

I want to call the js api with ajax.

```js
 
function stock(){
    ticker = $("#code").val();
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "http://hq.sinajs.cn/list=sh" + ticker,
        dataType : "script",
        cache : "false",
        timeout : 2000,
        success : function(data) {console.log(data);},
        error : function() {alert("wrong");}
    });
}
```

```html
 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    tiker:
    <input id="code" type="text" size="10">
    <input id="Search" type="button" onclick="stock()" value="query">
```

When you type `600020` in  ticker,and click `query`,no `wrong` info ,maybe my call to `http://hq.sinajs.cn/list=sh600020` is in good status.
The long string containing stock price info can't show in console,`undefined` in `console.log`'s window,
how to show the long string which is `http://hq.sinajs.cn/list=sh600020`'s response in `console.log`'s window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ticker is a variable ,you can type different numbers  in `input` whose  id is `code`,it means you search different company stock price.
`console.log(hq_str_sh600020)` means you can only search a specified company.

```js
 
function stock(){
    var ticker = $("#code").val();
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "http://hq.sinajs.cn/list=sh" + ticker,
        dataType : "script",
        cache : "false",
        timeout : 2000,
        success : function(data) {
            var sname = eval("hq_str_sh" + ticker);
            console.log(sname);},
        error : function() {alert("wrong");}
    });
}
```

```html
 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    tiker:
    <input id="code" type="text" size="10">
    <input id="Search" type="button" onclick="stock()" value="query">
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `dataType: "script"`, `.ajax()` will parse the response as javascript and execute it.

Here is the response...

> var hq_str_sh600020="中原高速,3.530,3.530,3.560,3.590,3.520,3.560,3.570,4517058,16087830.000,169746,3.560,114392,3.550,108100,3.540,153300,3.530,100000,3.520,129998,3.570,241810,3.580,346700,3.590,223900,3.600,148900,3.610,2018-09-19,15:00:00,00";

When executed, this script will create a global variable named `hq_str_sh600020`; this variable is what you should be working with.

Your success callback becomes:

```
success : function(data) {console.log(hq_str_sh600020);}
```

Example:

```js
 
function stock(){
    ticker = $("#code").val();
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "http://hq.sinajs.cn/list=sh" + ticker,
        dataType : "script",
        cache : "false",
        timeout : 2000,
        success : function(data) {console.log(hq_str_sh600020);},
        error : function() {alert("wrong");}
    });
}
```

```html
 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    tiker:
    <input id="code" type="text" size="10" value="600020">
    <input id="Search" type="button" onclick="stock()" value="query">
```

The documentation for [`.ajax() dataType: script`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) states...

> Evaluates the response as JavaScript and returns it as plain text

I do not know why your code doesn't log the plain text version of the script. Perhaps somebody else can provide that answer.